# int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1);

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

   int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1);  // what happens here ?

   printf("%d %d\n", *(a + 1), *(ptr - 1));

   return 0;
}
```

I expected the answer to be 1 but 'm getting 5 ..
Why ?

Comment: Surely, the output consists of two numbers, not one?

Comment: You are taking an address of an array and assuming it's the same thing as the address of its first element. It's not. The types are different, and the pointer arithmetic is different too.

Comment: oh yea.. i was talking only about *(ptr - 1)..
expected o/p by me - 2 1
Actual o/p  is - 2 5 ..

Anyways Daniel Fischer explained it !
Thanks

Comment: Yet another reason casting is absolutely evil.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1);  // what happen here ?
```

The address of the array is taken, and then 1 is added to it, which produces a pointer pointing `sizeof a` bytes past the beginning of `a`. That pointer is then cast to an `int*`, and that is assigned to `ptr`. The same could be achieved with

```
int *ptr = &a[5];
```

in this case.

Then `ptr - 1` is a pointer pointing `sizeof(int)` bytes before `ptr`, that is, to `&a[4]`, and `*(ptr - 1)` is `a[4]`.

Pointer arithmetic is done in units of "size of pointee". Since `&a` is a pointer to an array of 5 `int` - an `int (*)[5]`, adding 1 to it moves it `5*sizeof(int)` bytes.

Comment: ok.. then

int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 2);

then ptr-6 would yield the same result..

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. `(&a + 2)` is undefined behaviour, since pointer arithmetic is only defined when the resulting pointers point into the same array or one past the end. `(&a + 2)` would point two past the end. But in practice, although the behaviour is undefined, the probability that the implementation behaves as you expect for that, is nearly 100%.

Comment: oh ok..
There is very less probability that (&a+2) may not point at two past the end.. So its better to avoid those situation right ..

Thanks for the advice Daniel.

Answer (score 5):

`&a` is a pointer to pointer to `int[5]` and thus `&a + 1` is again a pointer to `int[5]`. Loose the `&` and all should be fine(and also you will no longer need the cast):

```
int *ptr = a + 1;
```

Comment: No, `&a` is an `int(*)[5]`, not an `int**`.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev isn't &a ==> &a[0] ?

Comment: @Arpit, same value different type and different pointer arithmetic

Comment: @JensGustedt you mean if i use `a` only then it will be converted to a[0] but if i use `a+int` then it's `&a[5]+int` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
int *ptr = (int*)(&a + 1);  // what happen here ?
```

a= address of first element of array: a[0] (address of int)

&a =address of array a,same value with "a", but type is address of array,so expression "(&a + 1)" is pointer to next array "a". 
(ptr - 1): pointer to previous int of ptr, that mean the pointer of last element of array "a".

Answer (score 0):

Array name holds the base address of the array. So, *(a+1) gives the element at the index position 1 which is 2. The expression (&a + 1) holds the address after the end of the array and the same gets stored in the pointer variable 'ptr'. So, *(ptr-1) gives the element stored at the last index position which is 5.